# Firebase loop fails with error (Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value)

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nodemailer

It seems my second await loop isn't working for some reason as I am getting the error `Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value` I am not sure how to structure this code to perform a function `send_email_process(subscribers, campaigns[index])`

```
(async () => {

    try {

        var campaigns = [];
        var coll = db.collection("campaigns");
        var query = coll.where("campaign_status", "==", "running").where("campaign_group", "==", "email");
        await query.get().then(function (querySnapshot) {
            querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
                campaigns.push(doc.data());
            });
        });

        if (campaigns.length !== 0) {

            console.log("Got here send_email");

            for (let index = 0; index < campaigns.length; index++) {

                const subscribers = [];
                const campaign_lists = campaigns[index].campaign_list;
                for (const campaign_list of campaign_lists) {
                    await db.collection("subscribers").where("subscriber_group", "==", "email").get().then(function (snapshot) {
                        snapshot.forEach(function (d) {
                            const subscriber_lists = d.data().subscriber_list;
                            for (const subscriber_list of subscriber_lists) {
                                if (campaign_list == subscriber_list) {
                                    subscribers.push(d.data());
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    });
                }

                send_email_process(subscribers, campaigns[index]);

            }
        }

    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Failed send_email: " + error);
    }

})();
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Mixing `await` and `then` is possible, but you'll need to be careful to return a promise from within the `then` as otherwise the `await` has nothing to wait for. Neither of your `then` handlers returns anything, so the `await` are likely meaningless.

How I'd do this when using `await` is to skip the `then` blocks and:

```
var coll = db.collection("campaigns");
var query = coll.where("campaign_status", "==", "running").where("campaign_group", "==", "email");
const querySnapshot = await query.get();

const campaigns = querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => doc.data());
```

And then do a similar removal of the `then()` in the second block of code.

Comment: Hi @Shina, does it [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) your question? Please consider upvoting and accepting it. Thanks